# mysql multiple value insert in one field

Tags: php, mysql

I have small issue in programming, first i added some test of patient in text area like this image, the number of textarea can increase according to  element of tests,[image]

so i want to to insert these in one field but only one part is updating in table
this is my record table where tests are stored`![enter code here][2]`

[image]

and after submit result i get only one result in my report table[image]

and this is my text area code

```
<div style="border:solid 2px #000; margin:2px;">
 <span style="padding:5px; font-size:14px; color:#FF0000;">{title}</span>
<textarea name="rep_result_" cols="75">{title}{txt}</textarea>
</div>
```

and i am inserting it with this code

```
gri("records","WHERE payment_id='$R[payment_id]' ","",$records);



    $dt = time();
    foreach($R as $k=>$v)
    {
        $test_id = str_replace('rep_result_', '', $k);

        if(strstr($k, 'rep_result_'))
        {
            $content = $v;
            $SQL = "INSERT INTO report SET
                   rep_te_id   = '$records[test_id]',
                   rep_result  = '$content',
                   record_id = '$records[id]',
                   rep_date    = '$dt'";
            ei($SQL);
        }
    }
```

so i just want to insert  all element test in one field, hope u understand for bad english i excuse, any idea will be highly appreciated...

Comment: Your INSERT statement looks like an UPDATE statement... INSERTS look like this: `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)`

Comment: @dirt it looks all right

Comment: my insert query is fine...@dirt

Comment: @dirt mysql supports update look likes insert statements, INSERT INTO .. SET ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing

```
<textarea name="rep_result_" cols="75">{title}{txt}</textarea>
```

with

```
<textarea name="rep_result[]" cols="75">{title}{txt}</textarea>
```

since you are using same name for different areas so php is taking only last textarea....
so you need the name as array..

Comment: @DineshKumar what is `gri` and `ei` are they user defined functions ... I havent heard of them in php..

Answer (score 0):

you can add [] to your textarea name like

```
<textarea name="rep_result_[]" cols="75">{title}{txt}</textarea>
```

so you will have an array of entered values with $_POST['rep_result_'], then iterate through them and insert table.